# JScrollPane scrolling issue

Tags: java, swing

Initially all the components are aligning only in the Horizontal direction in a single row.
Then I set the size of scroll enabled panel as below

```
main.setPreferredSize(scroll.getViewport().getSize());
main.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(scroll.getViewport().getWidth(),Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

And it worked the components start aligning in multiple lines,and not going beyond the screen horizontally. But why the vertical scroll is not happening, In fact the components are getting overridden, the height is also getting fixed as of viewport size even the maxsize is defined.

Please help.........

What i need is only vertical scrolling..... The components should not go beyond screen horizontally, but can go  beyond screen vertically.

**UPDATE with the code:**  Now all I want is the buttons should not go beyond the screen horizontally instead can use vertical scroll if the whole window is occupied.

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("JAVA GUI");
    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(main);  
    BoxLayout box = new BoxLayout(main, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    main.setLayout(box);    
    main.add(new JLabel("row 1"));      
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    for(int i=0;i<200;i++){     
        panel1.add(new JButton("b"+i));         
    }
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    for(int i=0;i<200;i++){     
        panel2.add(new JButton("b"+i));         
    }
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    for(int i=0;i<200;i++){     
        panel3.add(new JButton("b"+i));         
    }
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,10);
    panel1.setBorder(border);   
    panel2.setBorder(border);
    panel3.setBorder(border);
    main.add(panel1);
    main.add(new JLabel("row2"));
    main.add(panel2);
    main.add(new JLabel("row3"));
    main.add(panel3);
    frame.setContentPane(scroll);
    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: "But why the F***" - Now we have no idea what are you trying to say because of the ***.

Comment: What is scroll and how is it created before?  Unless you explicitly set the size of preferred size, don't assume it's set for ANYTHING.

Comment: Don't screw with the preferred/minimum/maximum size of the view port or scroll pane, it it will it will screw with you back.  The panel that is acting as the view, should be appropriate values for preferred/minimum/maximum size or implement the Scrollable interface to provide hints about how the viewport should be sized

Comment: Don't be abusive buddy, you are welcome if you are gentle.

Comment: Guys updated with full code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbars only appear when the preferred size of the component is greater than the size of the scrollpane.

A FlowLayout will wrap components, but it will not change the preferred size.

Check out the [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) which extends FlowLayout and will recalculate the preferred size for you when components wrap.

Answer (score 0):

As camickr pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21816061 , the main problem here is that the `FlowLayout` does not properly compute the preferred size of the component. The `WrapLayout` that he linked solves this issue basically. But in this case, this is still not sufficient, because the preferred size of the panels will simply be "as wide as necessary to show all buttons". In order to really wrap the buttons, you also have to replace your `main` panel with a panel that implements the `Scrollable` interface and returns `true` in `Scrollable#getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()`

```
class ScrollablePanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable
{
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()
    {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
        int orientation, int direction)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
        int orientation, int direction)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

So in your code:

```
JPanel main = new ScrollablePanel();  // Use ScrollablePanel here
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(main);  
...
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new WrapLayout()); // Use WrapLayout here
for(int i=0;i<200;i++){     
    panel1.add(new JButton("b"+i));         
}
```